# Excel: Array formula to sum values based on matching month and year results in value error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I am trying to sum a bunch of numeric values in

'Product Detail zPart (ALL TIME)'!$O:$O

using formula

```
{=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH('Product Detail zPart (ALL TIME)'!$F:$F)=MONTH(Summary!C$2))*(YEAR('Product Detail zPart (ALL TIME)'!$F:$F)=YEAR(Summary!C$2)),'Product Detail zPart (ALL TIME)'!$O:$O)}
```

to match month and year.

In (Summary!C$2) is a specific date and in 'Product Detail zPart (ALL TIME)'!$F:$F is the transaction date. It is giving me a value error and I am not sure why.

I know with array formulas you want to avoid the using the whole column, but for the sake of generating this report it needs to as the list of data in 'Product Detail zPart (ALL TIME)'!$F:$F will constantly be growing.

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this? I will also be adding two more criteria later once I have solved this part. I will need to match a Location name to the transaction as well as a product sku. Any advice would be muchly appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Summary Tab]

[image: Product Detail zPart (ALL TIME) Data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMIFS() and BookEnd the dates using EOMONTH:

```
=SUMIFS('Product Detail zPart (ALL TIME)'!$O:$O,'Product Detail zPart (ALL TIME)'!$F:$F,">=" & EOMONTH(Summary!C$2,-1)+1,'Product Detail zPart (ALL TIME)'!$F:$F,"<" & EOMONTH(Summary!C$2,0)+1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked like a champ. Another question for you, if you would indulge me. I tried to add two more criteria being the location name and the product SKU. I altered the formula to this.

=SUMIFS('Product Detail zPart (ALL TIME)'!$O:$O,'Product Detail zPart (ALL TIME)'!$F:$F,">=" & EOMONTH(Summary!C$2,-1)+1,'Product Detail zPart (ALL TIME)'!$F:$F,"<" & EOMONTH(Summary!C$2,0)+1,'Product Detail zPart (ALL TIME)'!$I:$I,"=Summary!A3",'Product Detail zPart (ALL TIME)'!$C:$C,"=Summary!C$1")

However, now the only value returned is 0.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `"=Summary!A3"` should be `Summary!A3` and the other just `Summary!C$1` no quotes.  the `=` is assumed.  @Preston

Comment: @Preston also do not forget to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.